# Can I cancel an API triggered send using Ampscript?

Tags: api, marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a way using Ampscript I can simply ignore or cancel the send request of an API triggered send?

Essentially I would like to "turn off" outgoing messages based on a variable within the API call. (e.g. If name is Andy then do not send)

Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you unable to check the attribute before sending the triggered send?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use RaiseError, give it a try: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/#RaiseError